# Chrome Extension Sync IndexedDB

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, synchronization, indexeddb

What is the most efficient way to sync indexeddb data from Chrome Extension?

- The first and most obvious choice is to use [chrome.storage.sync](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html).
- The second idea is to use [chrome.syncFileSystem](http://developer.chrome.com/dev/apps/syncFileSystem.html) and to dump the database into json.
- There is a third option to use a third party server which I don't want to.

The problem is that the database can contain a thousands of records also multiple indexes and etc. so I don't think neither of the first two choices is efficient. Not to say that chrome.storage is just a local storage and dumping and parsing the data into json for the second choice can get really messy and inefficient.

Comment: It seems that the most efficient way will be #3 specially for cases of thousands of objects. Why you don't want to use it?

Comment: I'm developing a chrome extension for the public so not everyone will want to sync their data on some third party server. But I have another idea: I will store only the queries issued to the database into the store.sync and then will execute the query queue on the other machine. It's just a proof of concept though.

Comment: I am developing library for syncing indexeddb with Google Cloud Storage, should be up in few weeks. Will that be useful? http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/transaction.html